# protobuf-net not deserializing 0's

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm using protobuf-net r278 in C#, and I just noticed that if I have a class with an `int` field, the field isn't deserialized properly if it's value is set to 0. Namely, when deserialized it gets its default value from the class definition. Example class:

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
public class
Test
{
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Field1 = -1

    [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2)]
    public int Field2 = -1;
}
```

Then run this code:

```
var test = new Test();
test.Field1 = 0;
test.Field2 = 0;
MemoryStream ms_out = new MemoryStream();
ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(ms_out, test);
ms_out.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var deser = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<Test>(ms_out);
```

When I do this, `deser` has `Field1 = -1` and `Field2 = 2`, not 0's. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In line with the wire-spec, there is an implicit zero default (which can be changed to other values with `[DefaultValue(...)]`. You can tell it to behave itself as you want by setting `IsRequired = true` in the attribute:

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true)]
```

Comment: Isn't behavior that a bug? This can easily lead to corrupted data that are difficult to figure out.

Comment: @mafutrct since there is no official spec for mapping to POCO and inferring a schema, that is impossible to answer; however, in v2 there is a switch to turn off the zero-default behaviour